# How to access the user id from a CATSSession object?

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have following line of code

```
<?php
    $userobject = $_SESSION[CATS];
    print_r($userobject);
?>
```

Which is giving me an output in at this way.

```
CATSSession Object ( [_siteID:CATSSession:private] => 1 [_userID:CATSSession:private] => 1262 [_siteCompanyID:CATSSession:private] => -1 [_userLoginID:CATSSession:private] => 184 [_accessLevel:CATSSession:private] => 200 [_realAccessLevel:CATSSession:private] => 200 [_isLoggedIn:CATSSession:private] => 1 [_isDemo:CATSSession:private] => [_isASP:CATSSession:private] => [_isFree:CATSSession:private] => [_isHrMode:CATSSession:private] => [_accountActive:CATSSession:private] => 1 [_accountDeleted:CATSSession:private] => [_siteName:CATSSession:private] => toppersedge.com [_unixName:CATSSession:private] => [_username:CATSSession:private] => savita [_password:CATSSession:private] => 6a8ce6560ef2e1bb577447dacc710fa7 [_firstName:CATSSession:private] => savita [_lastName:CATSSession:private] => savita [_email:CATSSession:private] => savita@toppersedge.com [_ip:CATSSession:private] => ::1 [_userAgent:CATSSession:private] => Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36 [_userLicenses:CATSSession:private] => 0 [_loginError:CATSSession:private] => [_checkBoxes:CATSSession:private] => Array ( ) [_dropdowns:CATSSession:private] => Array ( ) [_categories:CATSSession:private] => Array ( [0] => ) [_startTime:CATSSession:private] => 0.53573800 1534941193 [_endTime:CATSSession:private] => 0.10456100 1534941134 [_backupDirectory:CATSSession:private] => [_storedBuild:CATSSession:private] => 0 [_timeZoneOffset:CATSSession:private] => 1 [_timeZone:CATSSession:private] => 6 [_dateDMY:CATSSession:private] => 1 [_pipelineEntriesPerPage:CATSSession:private] => 15 [_storedData:CATSSession:private] => Array ( ) [_storedValues:CATSSession:private] => Array ( ) [_MRU:CATSSession:private] => MRU Object ( [_userID:protected] => 1262 [_siteID:protected] => 1 ) [_dataGridColumnPreferences:CATSSession:private] => Array ( [37e73d402d9ab7354df8059c91457059] => Array ( [rangeStart] => 0 [maxResults] => 15 [filterVisible] => [sortBy] => dateModifiedSort [sortDirection] => DESC ) [64b156082b85b493104a8ae2ac3dcce1] => Array ( [rangeStart] => 0 [maxResults] => 15 [filterVisible] => [startDate] => [endDate] => [period] => DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) [sortBy] => dateCreatedSort [sortDirection] => DESC ) ) [_dataGridParameters:CATSSession:private] => Array ( ) [_isFirstTimeSetup:CATSSession:private] => [_isAgreedToLicense:CATSSession:private] => 1 [_isLocalizationConfigured:CATSSession:private] => [_loggedInDirectory:CATSSession:private] => [_canSeeEEOInfo] => [_loggedInScript] => /ATS [__dataGridColumnPreferences] => Array ( [home:ImportantPipelineDashboard] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => First Name [width] => 85 ) [1] => Array ( [name] => Last Name [width] => 75 ) [2] => Array ( [name] => Status [width] => 75 ) [3] => Array ( [name] => Position [width] => 275 ) [4] => Array ( [name] => Company [width] => 210 ) [5] => Array ( [name] => Modified [width] => 80 ) ) [home:CallsDataGrid] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Time [width] => 90 ) [1] => Array ( [name] => Name [width] => 175 ) ) ) )
```

I just wanted to extract the user id from the object, how can I do this?

Comment: Have you try : $userobject->_userID ? But it's private normaly you got an error. You maybe have an getter method in your object to get your data

Comment: @Inazo You are right i am getting this `PHP Fatal error:  Cannot access private property CATSSession::$_userID`

Comment: `CATSSession` seems to be some custom class implemented in your system. Find the class file, read through it, and figure out the proper way to access what you need. There is probably some `getUserId()` method which you can call but without the class code I have no idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the source at https://github.com/opencats/OpenCATS/blob/master/lib/Session.php, you need to call...

```
$userobject->getUserID();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
              $userobject = $_SESSION[CATS];

              $id = $userobject->getUserID();


?>
```

See https://github.com/opencats/OpenCATS/blob/master/lib/Session.php